# What are $10^k \pmod 3$ and $n = \overline{a_ka_{k -1} \ldots a_1a_0}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I feel like I should know these concepts, but I don't.

Comment: Note that $10$ is congruent to $1$. So $10^k$ is congruent to ?

Comment: I know two integers a and b cab be congruent modulo n, but what does it mean for two integers to be congruent?

Comment: I was saving words. The modulus is $3$, I should have written that $10$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$.

Comment: For further context see the [OP's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878798/question-about-proving-division#comment1813376_878798) to their prior question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $\  n = a_k 10^k + \cdots + a_1 10 + a_0 = f(10)\,$ is a *polynomial* $\,f\,$ in $10$ with *integer* coeff's $\,a_i.\,$ Therefore, $\,{\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ \color{#c00}{10\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,f(\color{#c00}{10})\equiv f(\color{#c00}1) = a_k + \cdots + a_1 + a_0$ follows by applying the **Polynomial Congruence Rule** below. This is casting out *threes*, like [casting out *nines*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines)

---

**Congruence Sum Rule** $\rm\qquad\quad  A\equiv a,\quad B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c0f}{A+B\,\equiv\, a+b}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a) + (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{#c0f}{A+B - (a+b)} $

**Congruence Product Rule** $\rm\quad\ A\equiv a,\ \ and \ \  B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{blue}{AB\equiv ab}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a)\ B + a\ (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{blue}{AB - ab} $

**Congruence Power Rule** $\rm\qquad \color{}{A\equiv a}\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{A^n\equiv a^n}\ \  (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\ $ It is true for $\rm\,n=1\,$ and $\rm\,A\equiv a,\ A^n\equiv a^n \Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{A^{n+1}\equiv a^{n+1}},\,$ by the Product Rule, so the result follows by induction on $\,n.$

**Polynomial Congruence Rule** $\ $ If $\,f(x)\,$ is *polynomial* with *integer* coefficients then  $\ A\equiv a\ \Rightarrow\ f(A)\equiv f(a)\,\pmod m.$

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on $\, n = $ degree $f.\,$ Clear if $\, n = 0.\,$ Else $\,f(x) = f(0) + x\,g(x)\,$ for $\,g(x)\,$ a polynomial with integer coefficients of degree $< n.\,$  By induction $\,g(A)\equiv g(a)\,$ so $\, \color{#0a0}{A g(A)\equiv a g(a)}\,$ by the Product Rule. Hence $\,f(A) = f(0)+\color{#0a0}{Ag(A)}\equiv f(0)+\color{#0a0}{ag(a)} = f(a)\,$ by the Sum Rule.

**Beware** $ $ that such rules need not hold true for other operations, e.g.
the exponential analog of above $\rm A^B\equiv\, a^b$ is not generally true (unless $\rm B = b,\,$ so it follows by applying the Polynomial Rule with $\,f(x) = x^{\rm b}).$

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer:**

$X \pmod Y$ is the remainder of dividing integer $X$ by integer $Y$

So $X \pmod Y$ is equal to some integer value between $0$ and $Y-1$

Having said that, $X^k \pmod Y$ is equal to $[X \pmod Y]^k \pmod Y$

So $10^k\pmod3\equiv[10\pmod3]^k\pmod3\equiv1^k\pmod3\equiv1\pmod3=1$

Comment: $1 \pmod 3$ = $1$.  $\frac 13$ doesnt leave a remainder of 1. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Erbolat: In order to calculate $1\bmod3$: Divide $1$ by $3$. The number you get is made of an integer part and a fraction part. In this case, the integer part is $0$ and the fraction part $\frac{1}{3}$. You can throw away the integer part. Now, you take the fraction part, and you multiply it by $3$. The result of what you get is the answer to your question. In this case, $\frac{1}{3}\cdot3=1$, therefore $1\bmod3=1$. Let's do it again with $19\bmod7$: First, $\frac{19}{7}=2\frac{5}{7}$. Throw away $2$ and calculate $\frac{5}{7}\cdot7=5$. Therefore, $19\bmod7=5$.